# How can I "freeze" a rendered table?

Tags: c++, drawing, sdl

I have a table that I render like this:

```
void startRender() {
    this->x = 0;
    this->y = this->bord_y;
    constr_list(coords);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( this->rend, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF );
    for (int i = 0; i < this->cellsInColumn; i++)   {
        for (int j = 0; j < this->cellsInRow; j++)  {
            SDL_Rect outlineRect = { this->x + this->bord_x + (cellWidth*j), this->y+this->bord_y+(cellHeight*i), this->cellWidth, this->cellHeight  };
            SDL_RenderDrawRect( this->rend, &outlineRect );
            comp_in(coords, (this->x + this->bord_x + (cellWidth*j)), (this->y+this->bord_y+(cellHeight*i)));
        }
    }
}
```

I save the coordinates in a handwritten list for further processing. Furthermore, I tried to display the table in the same place where it was drawn using known coordinates.

```
void onlyRender() {
    comp* c = coords.head;
    this->x = c->coordX;
    this->y = c->coordY;
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( this->rend, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF );
    for (int i = 0; i < this->cellsInColumn; i++)   {
        for (int j = 0; j < this->cellsInRow; j++)  {
            SDL_Rect outlineRect = { this->x, this->y, this->cellWidth, this->cellHeight  };
            SDL_RenderDrawRect( this->rend, &outlineRect );
            if(c->next != NULL) { c = c->next; }
            else{ break; }
            this->x = c->coordX;
        }
        this->y = c->coordY;
    }
}
```

But the table is displayed below.

[image: startRender()]
[image: after onlyRender()]

*Question*: Can I make the table always appear in the same place? If so, how?

Comment: You shouldn't modify your class's stored coordinates when drawing.

Comment: @keltar the most interesting thing is that I do not change the coordinates. The problem is deeper

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**The root of the problem has been found**. If anyone is really interested, here was what happened.

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75289501/19796675) question of mine, when I couldn't draw the grid properly, I missed a very important point. I'm drawing the grid **OUTSIDE** the main program loop. Here is the code for the current main function:

```
int main( int argc, char* args[] ) {

    Manager* mainMan = new Manager(1360, 768, 30, 5);
    auto win = mainMan->getWindow();
    mainMan->start();

    if( !win.init() )
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        //Main loop flag
        bool quit = false;

        //Event handler
        SDL_Event e;

        //While application is running
        while( !quit ) {
            mainMan->moveBeam();
            //Handle events on queue
            while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 ) {
                //User requests quit
                if( e.type == SDL_QUIT )
                {
                    quit = true;
                }
                else if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
                    win.handleKeys( e.key );
                }   
            }
        }
    }

    //Free resources and close SDL
    win.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Function `mainMan->start()` draws a grid before the main logic of the program. At this point, for some reason, the image is rendered under the "decoration" or under the title bar. It looks like this:

[image: after mainMan->start()]

But when the program reaches the main loop `while( !quit )` everything changes. Now the program considers the first pixel of the window like the (0,0) coordinate, and not some pixel under the title bar. It looks like this:

[image: after mainMan->moveBeam()]

Maybe somewhere it was said about this feature of the work, but in any case, I found it myself by trial and error. Thank you all for your attention!